# how to enable xsi:nil in Zend framework for SOAP request

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, xml-nil

I need to make a SOAP request throw Zend_Soap_Client with making null-valued fields like

`<ns1:ValName xsi:nil="true"/>`

Right now I have such fields being translated as

`<ns1:ValName/>`

How can I enable 'xsi:nil'-translating in Zend?

Answer (score 0):

The nillable attribute indicates that the element that the attribute is on is present but has no value, similar to NULL in most programming languages.

If you want to assign a value to the element you can do so, however you'll have to remove the xsi:nil attribute first, otherwise you'll get an error.